# Find a limit using mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Using Mean Value Theorem how could I find the limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x+2)-f(x)}{x}$$ where $|f^\prime(x)|\leq\sqrt{x}$ for all $x.$

Comment: $|f(x+2)-f(x)|=2|f'(c_x)|$ for some $c_x\in(x,x+2)$. Squeeze...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{f(x+2)-f(x)}{2} = f'(y)$$ where $x < y < x+2$ which means

$$  -\sqrt{x} \leq \frac{ f(x+2)-f(x)}{2} \leq \sqrt{x+2} $$ which implies
$$-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{f(x+2)-f(x)}{x} \leq \frac{2\sqrt{x+2}}{x}$$
As $x \to \infty$ both $-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $\frac{2\sqrt{x+2}}{x}$ converge to $0$ and hence the required limit is $0$

Answer (score 4):

By the Mean Value Theorem there exists $c_x \in (x,x+2)$ such that

$$f'(c_x) = \frac{f(x+2) - f(x)}{2}$$

Now $$0\leq\Bigg|\frac{f(x+2) - f(x)}{x}\Bigg| = 2\Bigg|\frac {f'(c_x)}{x}\Bigg| \leq 2\frac{\sqrt{c_x}}{|x|}$$

As $x \to \infty$ we have that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x+2) - f(x)}{x} = 0 $$

by the squeeze theorem.